How do I edit specific fields using sed?
I am facing trouble just with the modify_record function in the code provided below. I could use Awk but my instructor told us to do it using sed. Could anyone help in this?
menu() {
    echo "choose one of the following options: \n"
    echo "1) create a student database"
    echo "2) view a student database"
    echo "3) insert a student record"
    echo "4) delete a student record"
    echo "5) modify a record"
    echo "6) display result"
    echo ""
}


create_db() {
    echo "creating a student database..."
    touch student.db
    echo "created a student database."
}


view_db() {
    echo -e "opening database... \n"
    cat student.db
}

insert_record() {
    echo -e "enter roll number: \c"
    read roll
    echo -e "enter name of student: \c"
    read name
    echo -e "enter marks of subject 1: \c"
    read sub1
    echo -e "enter marks of subject 2: \c"
    read sub2
    echo -e "enter marks of subject 3: \c"
    read sub3
    
    echo "$roll|$name|$sub1|$sub2|$sub3" >> student.db
    
}

delete_record() {
    echo -e "enter roll number whose info is to be deleted: \c"
    read roll
    grep -iv $roll student.db > temp.db && mv temp.db student.db
}

modify_record() {
    echo -e "enter roll no. whose info is to be modified: \c"
    read roll
    #echo -e "enter name: "
    #read temp_name
    echo -e "enter sub1 marks: \c"
    read newsub1
    echo -e "enter sub2 marks: \c"
    read newsub2
    echo -e "enter sub3 marks: \c"
    read newsub3

    sed -i "s/^$roll|\([^|]*\)|[^|]*|[^|]*||[^|]*\$/&\1|$newsub1|\2|$newsub2|\3|$newsub3/" student.db
}

calc_avg() {
    echo "enter roll no. whose average is to be calculated: \c"
    read rollno
    x=`grep $rollno student.db | cut -d'|' -f3`
    y=`grep $rollno student.db | cut -d'|' -f4`
    z=`grep $rollno student.db | cut -d'|' -f5`
    sum=`expr $x + $y + $z`
    average=`expr $sum / 3`
    # echo -e "average: $average\n"
    echo -e "average: $average\n"
}


while : 
do
    menu
    read -p "enter your choice: " choice
    
    case $choice in
    1) create_db ;;
    2) view_db ;;
    3) insert_record ;;
    4) delete_record ;;
    5) modify_record ;;
    6) calc_avg ;;
    7) break ;;
    *) echo "invalid choice"
    esac
done

The database which is created when you run this code looks like this:
rollno|name|sub1|sub2|sub3

The sed line in modify_record, rather than replacing the subject, marks it inserts them randomly in between other fields. I looked up other solutions and tried to copy their implementation but it didn't work.

/&\1 what is & doing here?

@KamilCuk i don't really remember ngl, I went around searching for other people having similar problems and also put this issue on ChatGPT, so it could be from any of those two

Your script has many other problems. Probably run it through https://shellcheck.net/

& is the whole line. You want to replace the line, not append.
sed -i "s/^\($roll\)|\([^|]*\)|[^|]*|[^|]*||[^|]*\$/\1|\2|$newsub1|$newsub2|$newsub3/" student.db


The following command replaces exactly fields 1,3,4,5 splitted by '|' character:
sed -i -e "s/[^|]*/$roll/1" \
       -e "s/[^|]*/$newsub1/3" \
       -e "s/[^|]*/$newsub2/4" \
       -e "s/[^|]*/$newsub3/5" student.db


Repeatedly running sed -i on the same file is a horrible antipattern. You want to combine these into a single script.

@tripleee Do you have another solution?

Basically, sed -i -e firstline -e second -e third -e fourth where firstline is your first sed script, etc. Seriously, this is not hard to google.
